# load page content via ajax without page postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my project , there are many contant pages under one master page , i want load those content pages using ajax when i click on hyperlink which is on master page. so provide solution with examples.

Answer (score 0):

use something like that

```
$('yourdivid').load('mycontent.html');
```

it will appear on specific div

Comment: Your div is missing a hash for id.

Comment: its an example i just say your div id

Comment: you have tu put #yourdivid its obivious

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why do you wanna have such a setup.

Anyway. Using jquery.

Load another page's content into the current page.

```
$('#DivOnCurrentPage').load('entireExternalPage.html');
```

or load one specific div from that page.

```
$('#DivOnCurrentPage').load('entireExternalPage.html #SpecificDivFromExternalPage');
```

note that you are not protected from same origin policy restrictions. [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If the external page you are loading contains javascript, that javascript will not be loaded into the current page. As for CSS, if you want to load css from that external page, load the entire page.